# How to reference product from database to "results" element with Wix Code

Tags: jquery, database, filter, reference, velo

I'm setting up a VIN decoder on my site and would like to have a product, from my Wix Store, display with the results in my "results".text user input element. As an example, when a user enters their VIN # in the input field, they receive a return of the year, make and model of the VIN # inserted. What I would like to do is have the appropriate and corresponding battery, from my WIX store, show with the results, based off the database I have set.

So far, I've tried to use the filter() method, which I could not figure out. Based on this article,
https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-data.WixDataFilter.html#eq, 
the code should function properly but I am not able to produce the function I am looking to achieve.

```
import {getVINInfo} from 'backend/VINModule';
import wixData from 'wix-data';


$w.onReady(function () {
    //TO DO: Write Your Page Related Code Here:


}); 

export function button1_click (event, $w) {
    //Add your code for this event here:
    getVINInfo($w("#vininput").value)
        .then(VINInfo => {
           console.log(VINInfo)
                     $w("#results").text = VINInfo.Results[8].Value + "  " + VINInfo.Results[5].Value + "  " + VINInfo.Results[7].Value + "  " + "  " + VINInfo.Results[47].Value; 
                     let results = $w("#results").text

               wixData.filter("batteryfitment")
        .eq("Year" + "Make" + "Model" + "Cylinders" + "Engine")
        .find()
        .then( (response) => {
          if(response > 0) {
            let battery = response.battery;
                                }
                                }) 
                            })


}
```

I expect the results to display the appropriate battery from my database which should show the correct battery from my Wix Store based off the year, make, and model given from the VINInput.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the filtering functions, such as `eq()`, correctly. There are two ways to use them:

1. If you're filtering a dataset, you can use them together with the dataset [`setFilter()`](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-dataset.Dataset.html#setFilter) function. In this case, you create a filter object like you have in your code above and pass it to `setFilter()`.
2. If you're executing a query, you can chain the filter functions to the [`query()`](https://www.wix.com/code/reference/wix-data.html#query) itself. In this case, you do not explicitly create a filter object.